# Find all directories containing a file that contains a keyword in linux

Tags: linux, shell, directory, find

In my hierarchy of directories I have many text files called STATUS.txt.  These text files each contain one keyword such as COMPLETE, WAITING, FUTURE or OPEN.  I wish to execute a shell command of the following form:

`./mycommand OPEN`

which will list all the directories that contain a file called STATUS.txt, where this file contains the text "OPEN"

In future I will want to extend this script so that the directories returned are sorted. Sorting will determined by a numeric value stored the file PRIORITY.txt, which lives in the same directories as STATUS.txt. However, this can wait until my competence level improves.  For the time being I am happy to list the directories in any order.

---

I have searched Stack Overflow for the following, but to no avail:

- unix filter by file contents
- linux filter by file contents
- shell traverse directory file contents
- bash traverse directory file contents
- shell traverse directory find
- bash traverse directory find
- linux file contents directory
- unix file contents directory
- linux find name contents
- unix find name contents
- shell read file show directory
- bash read file show directory
- bash directory search
- shell directory search

I have tried the following shell commands:

*This helps me identify all the directories that contain STATUS.txt*

```
$ find ./ -name STATUS.txt
```

*This reads STATUS.txt for every directory that contains it*

```
$ find ./ -name STATUS.txt | xargs -I{} cat {}
```

*This doesn't return any text, I was hoping it would return the name of each directory*

```
$ find . -type d | while read d; do if [ -f STATUS.txt ]; then echo "${d}"; fi; done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```sh
find -type f -name "STATUS.txt" -exec grep -q "OPEN" {} \; -exec dirname {} \;
```

or in a script

```sh
#!/bin/bash 
(($#==1)) || { echo "Usage: $0 <pattern>" && exit 1; }
find -type f -name "STATUS.txt" -exec grep -q "$1" {} \; -exec dirname {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. This is exactly what I was after. I find this approach to be most readable and it seems to execute faster than other approaches that people have suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try this:

```
grep -rl "OPEN" . --include='STATUS.txt'| sed 's/STATUS.txt//'
```

where grep -r means recursive , -l means only list the files matching, '.' is the directory location. You can pipe it to sed to remove the file name.

You can then wrap this in a bash script file where you can pass in keywords such as 'OPEN', 'FUTURE' as an argument.

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -rl "$1" . --include='STATUS.txt'| sed 's/STATUS.txt//'
```

Comment: You should probably have `--include="STATUS.txt"`, otherwise it will still return other filenames if they happen to contain `OPEN`

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply.  I have not had any luck with this command.  It seems to hang.

Comment: Correction:  It hangs for a couple of minutes and then return a huge list with a lot of false positives.  I think this might be what BroSlow was referring to with `--include="STATUS.txt"`

Comment: @Insertnamehere Yeah, you need to limit it by filename, which at least `GNU grep` can do, not sure if there is a way to do it with just `BSD grep`. As far as it taking a long time before printing a lot of results, it sounds like a buffering issue. You can try `--line-buffered`, although this will technically make the total runtime slightly longer.

Comment: @BroSlow thanks for pointing out the --include param, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Instead of the `sed` trick, you can avoid printing the file name with `grep -h`. Also, note that the `sed` you are using has `/g`, which shouldn't be necessary as you just want it to act once per line and `g` will make it as many times as `STATUS.txt` appears.

Answer (score 3):

... or the other way around:

```
find . -name "STATUS.txt" -exec grep -lF "OPEN" \{} +
```

If you want to wrap that in a script, a good *starting point* might be:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ $# -ne 1 ] && echo "One argument required" >&2 && exit 2
find . -name "STATUS.txt" -exec grep -lF "$1" \{} +
```

---

As pointed out by @BroSlow, if you are looking for *directories* containing the matching STATUS.txt files, this might be more what you are looking for:

```
fgrep --include='STATUS.txt' -rl 'OPEN' | xargs -L 1 dirname
```

Or better

```
fgrep --include='STATUS.txt' -rl 'OPEN' |
           sed -e 's|^[^/]*$|./&|' -e 's|/[^/]*$||'
#              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#            simulate `xargs -L 1 dirname` using `sed`  
#      (no trailing `\`; returns `.` for path without dir part)
```

Comment: +1. I would add grep option `-l` to simply output the pathname.

Comment: What is the `-f` supposed to be? On both GNU and BSD `grep` it's read the patterns from a file?

Comment: @BroSlow As far as I understand to OP needs, he wants to search for a _fixed string_, not a _pattern_. As he apparently wants to wrap that in a script, I thought it was a good idea to put emphasis on it. My mistake was to use a lower-case `f` instead of `F`. Stupid typo... Thanks to have noticed it!

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I think he also wants just the directory name, with the actual filename omitted. Otherwise you could just do something like `grep --include='STATUS.txt' -rl 'OPEN' .`

Comment: @BroSlow Good catch. I didn't see the tag 'Linux' -- and was looking for something "standard". What about `fgrep --include='STATUS.txt' -rl 'OPEN' | xargs -L 1 dirname` ?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply.  The command `fgrep --include='STATUS.txt' -rl 'OPEN' | sed -e 's|^[^/]*$|./&|' -e 's|/[^/]*$||'` certainly does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep` and `awk` instead of find:

```
grep -r OPEN * | awk '{split($1, path, ":"); print path[1]}' | xargs -I{} dirname {}
```

The above `grep` will list all files containing "OPEN" recursively inside you dir structure. The result will be something like:

```
dir_1/subdir_1/STATUS.txt:OPEN
dir_2/subdir_2/STATUS.txt:OPEN
dir_2/subdir_3/STATUS.txt:OPEN
```

Then the `awk` script will split this output at the colon and print the first part of it (the dir path).

```
dir_1/subdir_1/STATUS.txt
dir_2/subdir_2/STATUS.txt
dir_2/subdir_3/STATUS.txt
```

The `dirname` will then return only the directory path, not the file name, which I suppose it what you want.

I'd consider using Perl or Python if you want to evolve this further, though, as it might get messier if you want to add priorities and sorting.

Comment: I think that is good advice about using Perl or Python.  I will have to look into this next.  I was hoping that a shell script would be able to handle everything - I like to use the minimum number of packages possible.

Comment: Go with Perl, then. Almost every single *nix I've ever used comes with Perl out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Taking up the accepted answer, it does not output a sorted and unique directory list. At the end of the "find" command, add:

```
| sort -u
```

or:

```
| sort | uniq
```

to get the unique list of the directories.

Credits go to [Get unique list of all directories which contain a file whose name contains a string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111951/442338).

Answer (score -1):

IMHO you should write a Python script which:

- Examines your directory structure and finds all files named STATUS.txt.
- For each found file:

  - reads the file and executes `mycommand` depending on what the file contains.

If you want to extend the script later with sorting, you can find all the interesting files first, save them to a list, sort the list and execute the commands on the sorted list.

Hint: http://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/2011/03/26/traversing-a-directory-recursively/

Comment: To clarify, `mycommand` is intended to be executed once at the base level directory.  However, the approach of recursively executing some command at every directory where STATUS.txt contains a certain key - and using a scripting language (such as Python) to do so - is something that I am considering for future extension.  Thank you for the weblink.